# funtion roll takes the element at position n on the stack and makes it the top element

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a function called roll takes the element at position n on the stack and makes it the top element. For example, consider stack s as 1 2 3 4, where the left end is the bottom of the stack and the right end is the top (so the number 4 is at the top of the stack). roll(s, 2) will yield 1 2 4 3 and roll(s, 3) will yield 1 3 4 2.

Here is what I have so far

```
def roll(s: Stack, n: int):
    '''
    >>> roll([1,2,3,4], 2)
    1243
    >>> roll([1,2,3,4], 3)
    1 3 4 2
    '''
    s2 = Stack()
    if s.is_empty():
        return null
    else:
        s2 = s[::-1]
```

I have the hardest time when it comes to reversing lists and picking elements from it.

the instructions given say that the problem says you can't access element n positions from the top. You have to push the top n - 1 elements on a new stack. Get those elements back onto s after removing element n.

Comment: `s2 = s[:n]+s[n+1:] + [s[n]]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget can you give a small explanation how that works. Im confused about the s[:n] part and why is it s[n+1] if we are going technically backwards.

Comment: You're basically looking to remove one element and put it on top. So, you want the entire list, except for that element. If the element is placed at index `n`, then you want everything up to (but not including) `n`, and everything after `n`, in the order in which they are in the list. All that's the `s[:n] + s[n+1:]` part. The last step is to add `s[n]` back into your list, in the last position

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Doesn't this only work if we are going from left to right on the list and not right to left like in the question?

Comment: That part doesn't really matter to this - check out my code with your examples

Answer (score 0):

```
from stack import *

def roll (s, n):
    '''Perform the roll operation on s.'''
    t = Stack()

    for i in range (n - 1):
        t.push(s.pop())

    rollVal = s.pop()

    while t.isEmpty() == False:
        s.push(t.pop())
    s.push(rollVal)
```